# Does Postgres Logical Replication Provide Guarantees about the order of publication?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

Let's say I have a database schema with a monotonically increasing primary key, and this table is logically replicated across another database.  Is there same guarantee consistent in the replica?

As an example, is this a possible outcome when logically replicating with Postgres/Aurora?  Where transactions are replicated out of order?

```
master table    |                                         |replica table state 1 | replica table state 2 | replica table state 3 |
|pk| |trans_id| |                                         ||pk| |trans_id        | |pk| |trans_id        | |pk| |trans_id        |
 1        1     |                                         | 1       1            |  1       1            |  1       1            |
 2        1     | publish transaction 1 ----------------> | 2       1            |  2       1            |  2       1            |
 3        2     |                                         |                      |                       |  3       2            |
 4        2     | publish transaction 2 (out of order) -> |                      |                       |  4       2            |
 5        3     | publish transaction 3 (out of order) -> |                      |  5       3            |  5       3            |
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are scenarios where logical replication replicates data out of order. Either due to complex queries, large data transactions, lags etc. But logical replication is pretty consistent in the normal sense. But if you are relying on your serial primary key, you might want to consider using physical replication as it has a higher degree of consistency and also replicates strictly at the binary level.